# What are webhooks in the BugHerd API and how can they be created?

Tags: webhooks

I'm currently working with the [BugHerd API](https://www.bugherd.com/api_v2#api_webhook_list).

Please suggest how to create webhooks. I have google understand they are new functionality in apis and they used for two way communication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're a way of asking a remote server to make a request of your own server when events happen on the remote server. They allow you to receive real-time events without constantly polling the server. They're basically callbacks that happen between two severs over HTTP.

As for creating them, the API is pretty clear. Make a post request to `POST /api_v2/webhooks.json` and include JSON in the following format:

```
{
  "project_id":1,
  "target_url":"https://app.example.com/api/bugherd_sync/project/1/task_create",
  "event":"task_create"
}
```

You're telling it which event to hook into, and which URL their server should contact when the event occurs.

Comment: `They allow you to receive real-time events without constantly polling the server`, question for clarification - my server will still poll but instead sending HTTP requests each time it will just wait/poll until an event is sent from the remote server ?